# Apache+FastCGI Timeout Error: "has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds"

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, fastcgi

I've recently installed mod_fastcgi and Apache 2.2.
I have a simple cgi script as below (test.fcgi):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo sadjad
```

But when I invoke 'mysite.com/test.fcgi' I see "Internal Server Error" after a short period of time.

The error.log file shows this error message:

```
[Tue Jan 31 22:23:57 2006] [warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "~/public_html/oaduluth/dispatch.fcgi" has failed to remain running for 30 seconds given 3 attempts, its restart interval has been backed off to 600 seconds
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

What could the problem be? Is it my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run a CGI script through the FastCGI interface. That won't work. You can only run a FastCGI script, that follows the FastCGI specification, using the FastCGI interface. The server keeps running your script and trying to send it FastCGI requests and it keeps terminating without ever having received or processed any requests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your script. You must accept request before you print something to browser.

See the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339045/why-does-my-simple-fastcgi-perl-script-fail) on stackoverflow.com.